# How can one selectively apply -no-stack-protector to third party c++ code

Tags: c++, gcc

I am using -Wstack-protector switch while compiling my c++ code. Recently i have started using a third party library which reports warnings as errors because of -Wstack-protector. How can i selectively disable stack protection for parts of this third party code?